# How do you update a TextField from a grails remoteLink?

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails, gsp

Existing markup:

```
<g:textField name="identifier"/>
<g:remoteLink action="newId" update="identifier">generate new id</g:remoteLink>
```

Corresponding HTML markup:

```
<input type="text" id="identifier" name="identifier">
<a onclick="new Ajax.Updater('guid','/webapp/domain/newId',{asynchronous:true,evalScripts:true});return false;" href="/webapp/domain/newId">generate</a>
```

The HTML markup it generates when the link is clicked:

```
<input type="text" id="identifier" name="identifier">THE-NEW-ID-HERE</input>
<a onclick="new Ajax.Updater('guid','/webapp/domain/newId',{asynchronous:true,evalScripts:true});return false;" href="/webapp/domain/newId">generate</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add the following to the remoteLink:

```
onSuccess="\$('identifier').value=e.responseText;"
```

So the final result (which works perfectly):

```
<g:textField name="identifier"/>
<g:remoteLink action="newId" onSuccess="\$('identifier').value=e.responseText;">generate new id</g:remoteLink>
```

2 things to note:

1. the $ must be escaped due to the
   'grails' processing of that
   attribute.
2. I'm using the Prototype javascript library.  Other libraries may different syntax, but the basic idea is the same.

Comment: I can't get this to work with jQuery, tried multiple things.  Do you know how to get this to work in jQuery?  THanks

Comment: onSuccess="\$('identifier').value=e.responseText;" use 'data' instead of 'e' for jquery

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<div id="updatableArea">
  <g:textField name="identifier"/>
</div>
<g:remoteLink action="newId" update="updatableArea">generate new id</g:remoteLink>
```

In your controller return the HTML fragment

```
render(text:"<input type='text' id='identifier' name='identifier'>${newid}</input>", contentType:'text/html')
```

The remoteLink will simply update the contents of the node so it won't update the "value" of the textfield.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think you meant:

render(text:"<input type='text' id='identifier' name='identifier' value='${newid}'/>", contentType:'text/html')

In which case technically that might work, but it's more of a hack than I was looking for.

Comment: Yes that is what i needed. Your only other option would be to return some JSON and then fill the textbox using a Javascript Handler. As user299727 suggested

Comment: What returns from the ajax call is just a simple string (ie: "1234") would it be possible to somehow use the remoteLink 'onSuccess' event to run some javascript that updates the text field with the returned value?

Comment: nevermind, just figured it out and answered it myself.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another way using the onSuccess event:

```
def getName = {
   def exchange = Exchange.findById(params.id)
   if (!exchange) {
      render 'not found'
   }
   else {
      render(builder: "json") {
         exchange
      }
   }
}
...
<script>
   function fillName(e) {
      var obj = toJson(e);
      $('name').value = obj.name;
   }

   function toJson(obj) {
      return eval('(' + e.responseText + ')');
   }
</script>
...
<g:remoteLink action="getName" id="1" onSuccess="fillName(e)">
   Get
</g:remoteLink>
<input type='text' name='name' id='name'/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Took what you did and modified it to work for me in-line.